# How to enable a disabled button in Java for Selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, button, selenium-webdriver

I want to disable the button before clicking on it, here is what I have:

```
<button type="submit" name="shippingAddress_save" value="Continue to Billing >" disabled="disabled">
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com)! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. I suggest reading [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Also, be sure to take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 5):

you can do this in selenium USING **JavascriptExecutor**  as below:

```
WebElement yourButton= driver.findElement(By.name("shippingAddress_save"));

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].removeAttribute('disabled','disabled')",yourButton);

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(yourButton));

yourButton.click();
```

Comment: thank you but it is still saying "Element is not clickable at point (355, 1279)"

Comment: @kushal.8 From some reason the button is still disabled

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the properties in the html side after doing click with selenium, but you can't do it with selenium itself, selenium only does what you tell it to do, but if you want change in your UI or your behavior you must have to write code for it.

Answer (score 0):

you can check the below code :

`WebElement element=driver.Find(By.xpath("your locator xpath")); JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver; js.executeScript("arguments[0].removeAttribute('disabled','disabled')",element);`